# redis cluster: delete keys from smembers in lua script

Tags: redis

The below function delete keys from smembers, they are not passed by eval arguments, is it proper in redis cluster?

```
def ClearLock():
    key = 'Server:' + str(localIP) + ':UserLock'
    script = '''
        local keys = redis.call('smembers', KEYS[1])
        local count = 0
        for k,v in pairs(keys) do
            redis.call('delete', v)
            count = count + 1
        end
        redis.call('delete', KEYS[1])
        return count
    '''
    ret = redisObj.eval(script, 1, key)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right to be worried using those keys that aren't passed by an eval argument.

Redis Cluster won't guarantee that those keys are present in the node that's running the lua script, and some of those delete commands will fail as a result.

One thing you can do is mark all those keys with a common hashtag. This will give you the guarantee that any time node re balancing isn't in progress, keys with the same hash tag will be present on the same node. See the sections on hash tags in the the redis cluster spec. http://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec

(When you are doing cluster node re balancing this script can still fail, so you'll need to figure out how you want to handle that)

Perhaps add the local ip for all entries in that set as the hash tag. The main key could become:

```
 key = 'Server:{' + str(localIP) + '}:UserLock'
```

Adding the {} around the ip in the string will have redis read this as the hashtag.

You would also need to add that same hashtag {"(localIP)"} as part of the key for all entries you are going to later delete as part of this operation.